# multiplying Decimal and Integer throws "bad argument in arithmetic expression"

Tags: elixir, ecto

In my project I have to calculate a total price of a product by multiplying a price in Decimal to quantity in Integer. When I do so, I'm getting an exception "bad argument in arithmetic expression". How can solve that? I wouldn't want to lose data if I have to `round` a result.

Comment: Please provide the interesting code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elixir does not allow operator overloading, so the `decimal` package cannot make the `*` operator work on `Decimal`. The package does provide a function `Decimal.mult/2` to multiply `Decimal` values, which accepts 2 `Decimal` values, which you can use. You need to first convert the integer to a `Decimal` using `Decimal.new/1` and then use `Decimal.mult/2`:

```
iex(1)> d = Decimal.new("0.11111111111111111111")
#Decimal<0.11111111111111111111>
iex(2)> Decimal.mult(d, Decimal.new(3))
#Decimal<0.33333333333333333333>
iex(3)> 0.11111111111111111111 * 3 # This loses precision because Elixir's native floats are 64 bit IEEE floats
0.3333333333333333
```

Comment: sorry, I've forgotten to mention that it's from Ecto.

Comment: Ecto uses the `decimal` package so the exact same thing should work.